# Filtering an asset library in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, filter

I've created an asset library with the headshots of several hundred of my company's employees. I want people to be able to search for the photos by last name and image type. I've added both of those columns to the list.

I've created a page with a web part that displays the library, and have added a text filter on the page that connects to the library and searches the last name column. That filter works fine.

I'm trying to create a second filter that sorts by image type. There are only image 2 types - high-res and low-res. I've tried adding both a list filter and a choice filter, but when trying to establish a connection with the asset library, the only option Sharepoint offers is to connect with the "Search by Last Name" text filter that I've already created. It won't see the asset library that I want to connect with.

Is there a way to do what I'm describing? I've read about meta data filtering, but I don't think that'll quite do what I want. I'm working in Sharepoint 2010. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

List view web part only allows one connection at a time to filter, so you cannot use the way you described.

As a workaround, try to use data view web part to configure filters for the asset library in SharePoint Designer.